# The query requires an index. You can create it here: {link is broken}

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

I'm querying against my "GroupConvos" collection where the documents all have a `memberIds` string array with Ids about members that belong to that group and doing the following query for `GroupConvos` gives me with a broken link

```
self.db.collection(kGroupConvos)
       .order(by: kUpdatedAt, descending: true)
       .whereField("memberIds", arrayContains: self.currentUserId)
       .limit(to: 20)
       .getDocuments { [weak self] snapshot, error in
            if let error = error {
               print(error) 
            } else { ... }
```

> The query requires an index. You can create it here: {link}

Image:

[image]

So I went into the console and created an index:

[image]

And I keep getting that same error when I do my query. Any suggestions as to what to do here?

Comment: If you find a bug in the console, please file a bug report with reproduction steps: http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features

Comment: Submitted for you all. In the meantime while that auto-create index bug is fixed, do you have a recommendation for either my query or my index to make this work and avoid the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using array-contains to search a field, it looks like you need to add an Array Contains type index to it:

[image]

Notice that you have an option for that.  It looks like what you did instead was make memberIds an Ascending type field index.

Comment: Thanks Doug. I must have missed that option yesterday. Currently speaking with support about the console issue so hopefully that's ironed out soon. Have a good Thanskgiving!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, the correct index to prevent the index error for this query is:

arrayField: arrayContains
updatedAt: descending